# JOIN on 3 tables being slow

Tags: mysql, join, optimization

everyone.
Can't figure out what indices are missing or how to rephrase my query.
I created about a milllion of test entries in each table to see performance.  Query takes about 1.5 seconds which is infinitely more than what I need it to take (should be pretty much immediate).

Thanks for any help.

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `chars` (
  `pid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `x` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `y` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `z` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `zone` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `zonefrom` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `password` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `session` varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `surname` varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `bind_zone` varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `angle` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `bind_x` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `bind_y` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `bind_z` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `bind_angle` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `xp` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `hp` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `mana` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `endurance` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `copper` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `silver` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `gold` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `platinum` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `zoning_ts` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `clearance` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`pid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`),
  KEY `zone` (`zone`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1000004 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci



CREATE TABLE `inv` (
  `pid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `slot` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `institem` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`pid`,`slot`),
  KEY `pid` (`pid`,`institem`),
  KEY `institem` (`institem`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8



CREATE TABLE `institems` (
  `id` bigint(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `item` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `charges` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `container_slot_1` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `container_slot_2` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `container_slot_3` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `container_slot_4` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `container_slot_5` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `container_slot_6` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `container_slot_7` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `container_slot_8` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `container_slot_9` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `container_slot_10` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `amount` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `container_slot_1` (`container_slot_1`),
  KEY `container_slot_2` (`container_slot_2`),
  KEY `container_slot_3` (`container_slot_3`),
  KEY `container_slot_4` (`container_slot_4`),
  KEY `container_slot_5` (`container_slot_5`),
  KEY `container_slot_6` (`container_slot_6`),
  KEY `container_slot_7` (`container_slot_7`),
  KEY `container_slot_8` (`container_slot_8`),
  KEY `container_slot_9` (`container_slot_9`),
  KEY `container_slot_10` (`container_slot_10`),
  KEY `item` (`item`)
```

Query:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE chars.name 
FROM chars
    LEFT JOIN inv ON (chars.pid = inv.pid)
    LEFT JOIN institems ON (inv.institem = institems.id)
    WHERE
      inv.institem = 10001013730 ||
      institems.container_slot_1 = 10001013730 ||
      institems.container_slot_2 = 10001013730 ||
      institems.container_slot_3 = 10001013730 ||
      institems.container_slot_4 = 10001013730 ||
      institems.container_slot_5 = 10001013730 ||
      institems.container_slot_6 = 10001013730 ||
      institems.container_slot_7 = 10001013730 ||
      institems.container_slot_8 = 10001013730 ||
      institems.container_slot_9 = 10001013730 ||
      institems.container_slot_10 = 10001013730;
```

EXPLAIN of the above:

```
+----+-------------+-----------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table     | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                  | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | chars     | index  | NULL          | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL                 | 1000003 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | inv       | ref    | PRIMARY,pid   | pid     | 4       | evq_pok.chars.pid    |      10 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | institems | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | evq_pok.inv.institem |       1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-----------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------------+---------+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use plain `JOIN`, not `LEFT`

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE chars.name 
FROM chars
    JOIN inv ON (chars.pid = inv.pid)
    JOIN institems ON (inv.institem = institems.id)
    WHERE
      inv.institem = 10001013730 ||
      institems.container_slot_1 = 10001013730 ||
      institems.container_slot_2 = 10001013730 ||
      institems.container_slot_3 = 10001013730 ||
      institems.container_slot_4 = 10001013730 ||
      institems.container_slot_5 = 10001013730 ||
      institems.container_slot_6 = 10001013730 ||
      institems.container_slot_7 = 10001013730 ||
      institems.container_slot_8 = 10001013730 ||
      institems.container_slot_9 = 10001013730 ||
      institems.container_slot_10 = 10001013730;
```

It is obvious because with left joins you'll get alot of rows where `inv` and `institems` will be NULL and `WHERE` clause have no sense but make heavy load.

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems in the query is that indexes can't be used in the institems table. This is due to using OR in the search over several columns. I would normalize the institems table by moving all the container_slot_x into another table looking something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `container_slots` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `institems_id` bigint(11),
  `slot_no` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `slot_content` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`slot`),
  KEY `something` (`slot_content`,`institems_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

By doing this it is possible to use the index for quicker searches, without having to load the data of the container_slots table from disk, the index contains all the data needed.

While you are at it I suggest you try to normalize the chars table as well. Since I don't know the context I don't know if it is properly normalized or not, but based on the number of columns and the naming of them I don't think they are. I suggest having at least one table for the actual user (name, surname, password), one for the position details (x, y, z) and one for the character properties (xp, mana, money).